# Make a scrollable child div independent of the scroll of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[I am trying to make a scrollable div inside a another parent div.
but the height of the child div is not fixed, I want to make the child div scrollable independent
of the parent div scroll.How can I do it. is there a way to set a custom thumb sze for scrollbar of child as it covers the whole height of the child div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnX2q.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65783767/edit) your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

is it what you mean

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>

<style>
    .custom{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #EEE;
        border: 10px solid #CCC;
        margin: 30px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .child{
        height: 800px;
        width: 800px;
        background-color: #00F;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<div id="main" class="custom">
    <div class="child">
        child div
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but with height as 100% or having variable height

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow of the child div/element to auto to make it scroll:

> overflow: auto;

For scrollbar thumb you may find these useful:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/custom+scrollbar+thumb+size

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp